# View Controller Setup

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to figure out the best way to get my view controllers setup according to the design I am given. My app starts off with a full screen login screen. The user logs in and then the next view is a 3 tab screen. Where clicking on any control in any of the 3 tabbed view, need to take you to a full screen view controller.

Now the problem I am facing is that 
1) The guidelines say not to put a TabBarController in a NavigationController, which in this case I have to do. 
2) Also If I set the ViewControllers of each TabBarView to be a navigation controller, then I don't get the full screen space as the bottom always shows the tab bar, which I don't need to see.

Thoughts and pointers gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I would set it up would be to have a global container view controller that manages all of the internal view controllers.  Example:

```
=============================
= Container View Controller =
=============================
     |              |
------------   -----------
- Login VC -   - Main VC -
------------   -----------
```

Then, the workflow for app launch would be as follows:

1. Application launches and the container/splash view controller is the root view controller.
2. Container view controller determines login status (shows a loading indicator perhaps, etc).
3. Transition to the correct view controller.

If the user is not logged in, you could transition to the login view controller.  From there, you could subscribe to either a delegate callback or a notification which would be dispatched once the user logs in.  Once that message is received, you could re-check the login status and show the view controller accordingly.

If the user is logged in, at either the start or after receiving the login callback, then just show the main view controller.

Logout would work the same way as login.  Just push a notification to the container view controller and have it manage the view controllers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a tabBarController as your initial view controller.  If the user is not logged in, immediately present (modally) your login view controller.  Dismiss the login controller once the user has logged in, and return to the tabBarController.  Wrap the view controllers for each tab in a navigation controllers, but set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in order to hide the tabBar.